# How can I use a DbContext from a different assembly for my migrations?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I have multiple projects in a solution. For clean architecture reasons, I want to keep the DbContext in Infrastructure project, but my Startup Project is the API project. So the  Program.cs is in the API project.

I tried to specify that I wanted to use my context from the Infrastructure proect like this:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DzbcDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(
     builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
     b => b.MigrationsAssembly("DZBC.Infrastructure") )); // <- tried this
```

But it's not working. The error still tells me it's looking for the DbCOntext in the API project.

All similar answers are either old or don't work in .net core 6.

Comment: How do you try to add migration?

Comment: Check out  the parameters which you can pass to the command [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#common-options). You are looking for the `--project` one. If you are using VS Package Manager Console, then select correct default project there.

Comment: I just try to "add-migration initial" in project manager console.

Comment: Try selecting `DZBC.Infrastructure` in "Default Project" dropdown in the top middle/right part of  the "Package Manager Console".

Comment: Tried that but still no luck.

Comment: Can you please post [mre] somewhere?

Comment: Also if the project containing migrations and project containing `DbContext` AFAIK you don't need to specify the `MigrationsAssembly`.

Comment: There are no migrations yet because I can't execute the command. But I'd like to have them in the API project. When creating the API project I used the API template, but Infrastructure is just a class library. Maybe that's the problem?   I'll get on the minimal reproducible example in 30 mins.

Comment: _"There are no migrations yet because I can't execute the command. But I'd like to have them in the API project."_ - then you should specify it as migration assembly. _"but Infrastructure is just a class library. Maybe that's the problem?"_ it should not be.

Comment: Can you please at least post full error text?

Comment: Solved it. Will post answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved by forcing it in Developer PowerShell.

Navigate to the project folder where you have your DbContext (in my case Infrastructure). From there use this:

```
dotnet ef migrations add initial --startup-project "../DZBC.API/DZBC.API.csproj"
dotnet ef database update --startup-project "../DZBC.API/DZBC.API.csproj"
```

But use the .csproj path of your Startup project.

Comment: It should work the other way around. You should be able to do the same using current startup folder and specifying target project ([see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#target-project-and-startup-project)).

Comment: How about set the "-ProjectName" when adding migrations or updating database?

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues I tried that, didn't work.

Comment: @GuruStron I'll try that next time. Not sure what went wrong.